# Why does is my updated DNS record not seen by localhost?

Tags: dns

Suppose I own the domain `example.com` and control its DNS server. (To be clear, I do not own `example.com`.)

I just recently (about an hour ago) updated the dns for `a.example.com` to point at the IP address of a Linode that I am renting. Note that `a.example.com` previously did not point at anything.

Now, on localhost, I try the command `ping a.example.com` and get the error `unknown host a.example.com`. This is suprising to me, because I had just pointed the subdomain and I do not expect there to be cache of the domain already in the recursive resolver at any level. More specifically, I would expect one of the recursive resolvers upstream of me to query the authoritative nameserver (which I just configured), and discover the correct IP Address.

As an additional experiment, I tried the same command `ping a.example.com` from a different virtual server in Digital Ocean's cloud, and it resolved to the correct IP address.

**Why are some reasons that localhost might fail to see the new DNS entry?**

**How might I force localhost to see the DNS entry for the subdomain?**

Note that I am using Google DNS and running Ubuntu 14.04 on localhost.

Comment: Since `foo.com` is a real domain owned by a real organisation you might want to choose a different one. `example.com` perhaps?

Comment: @roaima, Given that I've already indicated that I do not own the domain, is this relevant to the question?

Comment: It's not relevant to the question but it might be relelvant to the domain owner, which is why I raised it. Either way, I'm still pondering your underlying issue. Can you offer your real domain record, please? So's I can review the DNS records, glue, etc.

Comment: posting the output of dig a.foo.com from localhost might help; about your second question, edit /etc/hosts while you don't get the hostname resolved correctly.

Comment: @guido, I just looked at the dig entry and it is pointing at something completely random. There's something strange happening upstream.

Comment: @merlin2011 in the dig output, you have to take notice of server comment on the third line from the bottom; then try `dig @8.8.8.8 a.foo.com`

Comment: @guido, I just resolved the issue internally with my university network.

Answer (score 1):

If you updated one hour ago maybe the propagation isn't finished yet?

You might want to check [what's my dns](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) to be sure that your new dns resolution has spread everywhere.